# Expectation value of $p^2$ for an arbitrary real state function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, momentum, wavefunction

I'm trying to obtain the expectation value of momentum squared for a real state function $(\Psi^*=\Psi)$.

I already know that

\begin{equation}
\left <p \right >=0
\end{equation}

for a real state function. I got this by manually operating the integrals defined by the expectation value. I tried the same method for $p^2$ but I got nowhere $(0=0)$.

I found that one can say that this arbitrary real function it's, actually, $ \Psi_k= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx})$, and then generalize the argument for a state function that is a linear combination of $\Psi_k$, and hence, an arbitrary real state function. Then, when I compute $\left < p \right>$ I get that $\left < \Psi_k | p | \Psi_k\right> =0$, as expected. Then, using this same argument for $\left < \Psi_k | p^2 | \Psi_k\right>$ I get that the integral defined diverges.

I'm really on a dead-end here, since I don't know any other way to approach this problem. The fact that $\left <p \right >=0$ makes me think that $\left <p^2 \right >=0$, but this would imply that the expected value of the kinetic energy of the particle is zero, which can't be true (or can it?). Also, the fact that $\left < \Psi_k | p^2 | \Psi_k\right>$ diverges makes me think that the kinetic energy is infinite, which is also wierd.

Comment: There are plenty of functions for which $\langle p\rangle=0$ but $\langle p^2\rangle\neq 0$. For example, any of the harmonic-oscillator eigenstates have this property.

Comment: If $\langle p^{2} \rangle = \langle p \rangle = 0$, it implies that $\Delta p = 0$. So, the wave function is an eigen-state of momentum operator.

Comment: If anyone runs into this question, I may say that I solved this problem by making use of the Hamiltonian operator. I used its definition and found a explicit expression of the expected value of $\left< p^2 \right>$, but I wasn't able to find the restriction or special result of using a real-valued state function, as in the case of $\left< p \right>$.